# Qt 5.8.0 MSVC - Getting a weird compiler error

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I have been using this version of Qt & the MSVC compiler great... for about 15 minutes. :| All of a sudden while revising some projects & converting others from QWebkit to QWebEngine, I stumbled upon an error at step `make` I thought "So what? I've seen this tons of times." But then I saw this int he kit errors:

`qt compilers produce code for different ABIs`

Never seen it before. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the Compile output.

```
jom: C:\Users\Thatr\Documents\Qt\build-E621Downloader-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
18:45:04: The process "E:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project E621Downloader (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015_64bit)
The kit Desktop Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015_64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
```

EDIT: Here is a list of my available compilers.

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 14.0 (x86)
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 14.0 (amd64_x86)
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 14.0 (amd64)
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 14.0 (x86_amd64)
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 14.0 (x86_arm)
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 14.0 (amd64_arm)
MinGW (x86 64bit in C:\Strawberry\c\bin)
MinGW (x86 32bit in C:\Strawberry\c\bin)
```

Here is the Compile Output:

```
16:02:14: Running steps for project EAGalleryDownloader...
16:02:14: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
16:02:14: Starting: "E:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    E:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    E:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\bin\uic.exe ..\EAGalleryDownloader\mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
jom: C:\Users\Thatr\Documents\Qt\build-EAGalleryDownloader-Clone_of_Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [ui_mainwindow.h] Error 2
    E:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WEBENGINE_LIB -DQT_WEBENGINEWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_WEBENGINECORE_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WEBCHANNEL_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_POSITIONING_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB --compiler-flavor=msvc --include debug/moc_predefs.h -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/mkspecs/win32-msvc2015 -IC:/Users/Thatr/Documents/Qt/EAGalleryDownloader -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtWebEngine -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtWebEngineWidgets -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtWebEngineCore -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtQuick -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtPrintSupport -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtWidgets -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtGui -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtANGLE -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtWebChannel -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtQml -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtNetwork -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtPositioning -IE:/Qt/5.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtCore -I. -I"E:\Visual Studio\VC\INCLUDE" -I"E:\Visual Studio\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" ..\EAGalleryDownloader\mainwindow.h -o debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp
jom: C:\Users\Thatr\Documents\Qt\build-EAGalleryDownloader-Clone_of_Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
16:02:15: The process "E:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project EAGalleryDownloader (kit: Clone of Desktop Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015_64bit)
When executing step "Make"
16:02:15: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

[image]

Comment: It is stated that your kit has configuration issue, please add your screen shot of your kit here also

Comment: @Apin Just posted the kit image.

Comment: Your C++ compiler says x86. Your Qt build is 64 bit. Did you try selecting a different compiler in the kit clone? Auto detected kits sometimes bork up.

Comment: @ddriver Hey! Nice to see you again. I tried every compiler that I have. I will add a list of them to the post.

Comment: That;s a lot of compilers. I'd try the amd64 version.

Comment: @ddriver I've tried every single one. Still the error :/

Comment: You're not supposed to try every single one. You're building a 64 bit project using **hopefully** a 64-bit build of Qt. You have **no choice** in the matter: use the same compiler that was used to build Qt: it will be the `amd64` one. And delete the build folder before you attempt to build the project again.